# Portfolio Theory - Finance Riskless Assets Return

Tags: finance, risk-assessment

A market consists of two risky assets and one riskless asset.
Asset 1 has a return of 8% and a risk of 10%.
Asset 2 has a return of 16% and a risk of 30%
The correlation between the returns of the two assets is - 1 (minus one)

a) Find the weights of a portfolio consisting of Asset 1 and Asset 2 only which has zero risk.

b) What is the return of the riskless asset in the market?

I believe i have solved question a but am unsure. I used the equation σp=|w1σ1 - w2σ2| as we have a correlation of -1. rearranging to find the weights as .75 and .25

However when i come to b i have no idea where to start, any guidence as to where to begin would be helpful

Comment: How about $r_p = w_1 r_1 + w_2 r_2$ with $r_i$ the respective returns and $w_i$ the calculated weights

Comment: Oh true, forgot one of the most basic formulas! was trying to over complicate it. Thanks

Comment: I wrote the comment as an answer so the question can be accepted in order to remove it from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

Just use
$$r_p = w_1 r_1 + w_2 r_2 = \frac34 \cdot 0.08 + \frac14 \cdot 0.16 = 0.1$$
So the combined return is $10\%$.